# attached to his mom all day?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

If a boy is very clingy to his mom, does the following sentence sound natural?

The boy is attached to his mom **all day**.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I think 'The boy was attached to his mom all day' is what you're trying to convey, considering that the day being talked about has already passed.

Comment: Does "The boy was attached to his mom all day" mean "the boy clung to his mom all day"?

Comment: Yes! You're exactly right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words **clingy** and **attached** are both figurative and literal; they refer to emotional dependency which may manifest itself in physical ways: the child might want to have his hand held, or might want to hold onto his mother's dress.

The phrase **all day** runs counter to the figurative meanings, and so one would assume you had only the literal meaning in mind, that the mother has him "in tow" all day, or that he's close by her side.  It would not necessarily imply any sort of emotional dependency.

Comment: Does "The boy was attached to his mom all day" mean "the boy clung to his mom all day"?

Comment: The word **attached** can be used as a form of exaggeration to describe situations where someone is never alone or separated by distance from another person, but is always in their company.  So *the boy is attached to his mother all day* could refer a situation where the boy does not go to nursery school or kindergarten, has no babysitters and possibly no playmates, but is in the company of his mother all day.  It could also mean that he clings to her all day, literally. He is always clutching her dress, or something like that.  It is not a precise term.